# GTA 5 won't play on Xbox 360 due to missing compatibility packs?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I am trying to play GTA 5 online on my Xbox 360, but it made me download the compatibility packs. I downloaded them on the hard drive I use to play GTA 5 instead of the memory unit. It says that they are all installed, but it still won't let me play.

Do I have to download it on the memory unit or is there something wrong with the hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have not experienced this problem personally, but given that GTA V has had many updates, it might be a problem of a missing (or needing yet another) compatibility pack.

Try installing them again, and double check you've got them all. Otherwise, wait until the next update.

Answer (score -6):

Restart your Xbox okay if that doesn't work then I don't know